# Visual Studio Remote Debugging (2017) errors

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

whenever I want to remote debug a project (C# or native C++) in Visual Studio 2017 I currently get the following errors. These errors do not appear if I directly attach to a prior running process.

With Visual Studio 2015 remote debugging of the same projects did work like a charm.

Any ideas?

Error 1:

[image]

Error2:

[image]

Comment: You'll probably have a lot more luck if you set your OS language to English and re-post those messages. You're heavily limiting your audience by posting in German.

Comment: Thanks, I will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question:

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 15.3.1 remote debugging works as expected.